# GRUB slow respond to key press

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

So, I new into Linux, Ubuntu and that stuff, but I think I like it.

My problem is, the first key pressed after GRUB shows up, GRUB needs really long (about 2-5 seconds) to show any respons, after that it's fine.

Can I somehow fix this?

The exact same problem, but the answers didn't help : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060058